# preg_replace usage or alternative

Tags: php, preg-replace

So I need to filter/replace text in PHP to make sure there are spaces around dashes.

Example: "Shirts-general" needs to become "Shirts - general"
but I don't want extra spaces, so "Shirts - general" does change to "Shirts  -  general"(with 2 spaces on each side of the dash.

There will always be a space or text on each side of the dash.

Right now I am using the following and it works, but takes forever (I am checking about 900,000 variables with this code). When I added this my script went from 4 minutes to 52 minutes.

```
$myText = preg_replace("/(.)(-)(.)/", "$1 - $3", $myText);
```

Ideas?

Comment: Don't know, what "an entry" is in your case, but "from 4 minutes to 52 minutes" sounds, that it does very much more, than just this simple replacement.

Comment: My script does far more, but this is the part that is taking all the time. I think with the way I am using preg_replace is not the best way to achieve what I need, but I haven't been able to find a better option.

Comment: @EricImprint I've also added a non-regex solution to my answer. I'd be curious to find one which performs faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should be faster:

```
preg_replace("/ ?- ?/", " - ", $txt);
```

And here's a variant with only one call to str_replace:

```
str_replace(array(' -', '- ', ' - ', '-'), array('-', '-', '-', ' - '), $txt);
```

Here's an example of both working: http://codepad.org/zqf4LRVD

I'm too lazy to do the performance comparison, but I would be curious to find out which is faster.

Comment: Thanks. I think the double str_replace option is a faster fit.

Comment: Actually making only one str_replace call will be faster, the only difference is if you only do it with only 2 elements or with 4 as I've written it. If you can't have spaces on only one side, you can simplify the arrays.

Comment: I am trying to make sure that is one space and only 1 space on each side of the dash no matter what. I will give your array version a try and let you know if it is faster than having two str_replace calls.

Comment: I just ran a test and I got that your second solution is the fastest. You can also speed it up by removing 2 of the tests: `str_replace(array(' - ', '-'), array('-', ' - '), $txt);` since there will only be 1 space on each side or no space.

Comment: The str_replace with the 4 part array ended up being about 20% faster than the preg_replace. (for my data)

Comment: Interesting to know - a few more options and probably the regex engine would have been on par.

Answer (score 1):

This should be faster: `preg_replace( "/\\s*-\\s*/", " - ", $myText );`.

Comment: Thanks. I think the double str_replace option is a faster fit.

Comment: As draevor points out, thelastshadow's response will not work if there are only spaces on one side. It will also not work if there is more than one space. This takes care of both those cases.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's as quick as you'll get. You can try a double str_replace

```
$once = str_replace("-", " - ", $content);
$twice = str_replace("  -  ", " - ", $once);
```

this will obviously only work if you're not worried about having double spaces to begin with

Comment: Or if you have spaces on only one side - in that case you will have to do 4 replaces.

Comment: Sometimes the best answer is the simple one. Thanks. My ego just took a hit for not thinking of that. I will update my script and let you know how it goes.

Comment: indeed. preg_replace is really what you're after here unless you know what you've got to begin with.

Comment: I do know what I have coming in, it will be text-text or text - text, so this should work.